# Bullet physics in python and pygame

Tags: 2d, python, pygame, bullet-physics, side-scroller

I am programming a 2D sidescroller in python and pygame and am having trouble making a bullet go farther than just farther than the player.  The bullet travels straight to the ground after i fire it.  How, in python code using pygame do I make the bullet go farther.  If you need code, here is the method that handles the bullet firing:

```
    self.xv += math.sin(math.radians(self.angle)) * self.attrs['speed']
    self.yv += math.cos(math.radians(self.angle)) * self.attrs['speed']
    self.rect.left += self.xv
    self.rect.top += self.yv
```

Comment: This is way too vague, you should post some snippets of code (not the whole program).

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what happens to the bullet.

Does it have the same speed as the player? In that case, obviously the bullet should have a greater speed.

Does it disappears just after it appeared? Maybe you misplaced it and collided with the player.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 2D physics engine that integrates nicely with PyGame. It is called [PyMunk](http://www.pymunk.org) and uses the [Chipmunk](http://chipmunk-physics.net) 2D physics engine. You might want to use it if you do something more with physics in your games.

Comment: This does not appear to really address the asker's issue.